# How to read data from excel and set data type

Tags: python, arrays, excel, list, types

I am trying to read in latitude and longitude data from a csv file and calculate bearing successively using harversine formula.

I have to pick up the lat/lon from one row then calculate bearing against the lat/lon in the next row.

I updated the codes and now I am getting this error:

```
indexes = [x.index for x in self.objs]
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'index'
```

I can't figure out how I can set data type to float for array. I wonder if someone can help me on this? Thank you.

Update ... below is the working code.

---

```
import pandas as p
import numpy as np

bearingdata = 'xxxxxx.csv'
data = p.read_csv(bearingdata)

lat = [float(i) for i in data.Lat]
lon = [float(j) for j in data.Lon]

lat1 = lat[0: (len(lat) -2)]
lon1 = lon[0: (len(lon) -2)]
lat2 = lat[1: (len(lat) -1)]
lon2 = lon[1: (len(lon) -1)]
```

then def() .....

Comment: can you do a `print type(lon1)` just to make sure the data is in the right type? also, is the `radians` function one defined by you or from some library? if that's the case, you can compose a float conversion and then the `radians` function call after.

Comment: Just `map(lambda a: radians(float(a)), [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2]))`.

Comment: Aside from possible problems with `radian`, are there non-numeric entries in your csv? Pandas should detect dtype automatically. What is `data.Lat.dtype` and try `data.Lat.astype(np.float64)`

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for your input! I am revising the code and will get back to you ...

Comment: So I could get a super help and I updated the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pyexcel, this job can be done easily too:

```
>>> import pyexcel as pe
>>> sheet = pe.load("xxxxx.csv")
>>> sheet.format(float)
>>> sheet.name_columns_by_row(0)
>>> lat = sheet.column["Lat"]
>>> lon = sheet.column["Lon"]
....# more processing here
```

Comment: Hi chfw, thanks for your comment. That's a good idea. Actually, it turned out that I didn't need 'from math import *' in my script. Then then the original script worked.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to re-iterate ... below is the final code.

```
import pandas as p
import numpy as np

bearingdata = 'xxxxxx.csv'
data = p.read_csv(bearingdata)

lat = [float(i) for i in data.Lat]
lon = [float(j) for j in data.Lon]

lat1 = lat[0: (len(lat) -2)]
lon1 = lon[0: (len(lon) -2)]
lat2 = lat[1: (len(lat) -1)]
lon2 = lon[1: (len(lon) -1)]
```